# How can I convert this code into a recursive function? Base case analysis

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter width: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
           if (i == j || (i + j + 1) == n) {
               printf("X");
           } else {
               printf(" ");
           }
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I convert this code into a recursive function? I am having trouble with the "base case" I am trying to work with this line

```
void recursiveProblem(int num, int max) {
    if (num <= (max / 2 + 1))
        ...
}
```

so if I reach halfway I can print the middle line and return it, but it's not working. This function will print a large X made from x's?

Comment: Why would you anyone want to use recursion for this problem? There are enough problems where recursion is an elegant solution to avoid torturing students with stupid requirements.

Comment: @chqrlie ikr... you should see the questions on cppinstitute for C programmers... all this verbosely complex pointer arithmetic that would get even the most decorated engineer shot haha

Comment: "it's not working" is always a bad problem statement. Instead, always describe what happens, what you expect and why you expect it. This applies every time you describe a bug to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

To solve tasks using recursion, you can use this pattern:

- to solve the task:

  - check if you've reached a trivial case. If so:

    - do the trivial thing
  - otherwise:

    - split the task into smaller parts that look similar to the whole task
    - solve each of the smaller tasks by calling the function recursively

In your case the task is `print_diagonals(width_of_the_square, current_line_number)`.

Defining this task by giving it a proper name and by finding out the parameters and their names is the most important part of solving this kind of problems. It's much easier to think about `print_diagonals` than about `recursiveProblem` since the names I've given carry lots of meaning and exactly describe their purpose.

The "trivial case" in this task can be either "print the line in the middle of the square" or "print the bottom line of the square". Both will work, and the programs will look similar. Try them both and then compare the resulting programs. The part these programs have in common is typical for recursive programs.

Using this information, you should be able to do your homework by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why anyone would want to make this recursive.  But this works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recurse(int i, int j, int n){
    printf(i==j || i+j+1==n ? "X" : " ");
    if (++j == n) {
        printf("\n");
        if (++i == n)
            return;
        j=0;
    }
    recurse(i, j, n);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter width: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    recurse(0, 0, n);
    return 0;
}
```

If you'll notice, I move one `if` block right inside the `printf` statement using the `? :` operator.

Also, notice that every single `printf` is called from it's own `recurse` function call, which is on top of every other function call on the stack.  So if your stack is limited and `n` is large, you could run out of stack and crash.  This is one reason recursive functions should only be used with caution.

Alternately, you could put the loop that increments `j` in the recursive function and only recurse to increment `i`.  That would use a lot less stack.

Comment: For a programming student it's essential to learn how to analyze problems and think about them. Giving them only the finished code without any explanation is not helpful.

Comment: He could very well be learning C on his own.  Many have.  He didn't say he was a student.

Comment: ken: a student is someone who is learning, and @roland's comment applies equally to self-learners.